# How do I store int values from CSV file in separate two-dimensional array elements

Tags: java, arrays, csv

If I have a CSV file with 4 numbers on one line separated by a comma, how do I ignore the first two values using openCSV?

Now, consider the following two-dimensional array:

```
int[][] data = new int [10][10];
```

and the following line from a CSV file:

```
54, 68, 5, 1
```

assuming the former is possible (ignoring the first two values on a line in a CSV file), how do I then parse the value '5' into data[0][0] and parse the value '1' into data[0][1]?

i.e.:

```
data[0][0] = 5;
data[0][1] = 1;
```

Of course, if you cannot ignore the first two values, how do I parse each value (54, 68, 5, and 1) all in separate array elements?

i.e.:

```
data[0][0] = 54;
data[0][1] = 68;
data[0][2] = 5;
data[0][3] = 1;
```

I can't find anything in the openCSV documentation that would explain how to do this, nor can I wrap my head around even doing it if there weren't a CSV file to read beforehand.

Comment: Good you're using a CSV library instead of a regex or simplistic "jump at the commas" parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just googling "opencsv" got me to [its project page](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). That page has the following example:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
   System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

What prevents you from doing the same and just accessing the fields you want by index?

```
data[0][0] = nextLine[2];
data[0][1] = nextLine[3];
```

Comment: Well, you're right! A bit embarrassing seeing as I was looking at that exact example for about 20 minutes trying to figure out how I might get it to work for my needs. I guess a second pair of eyes looking at the problem from a different angle really does do wonders. Thanks Robert.